# Xcode, How to record pop up menu selected option into Firebase database

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, popup

I am creating a user registration page, for some information such as Email and password I use UITextField, but for mutually exclusive information such as University and Student Accommodation I am using a button which can have its title altered when a pop up option is selected. My problem is that I am confused as to how I can record the specific option that's selected from the pop up menu.

**This is the button:**

```
private let University: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("University", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        button.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true //cuts of anything tht overflows the layered corners
        //button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .regular)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 3 
        return button
    }()
```

**This is the function that allows for pop up menu:**

```
func UniPop(){
        let Uni = {(action: UIAction) in
            print(action.title)}
//        let button = UIButton(primaryAction: nil)
        University.menu = UIMenu(children: [
            UIAction(title: "University of Warwick", handler: Uni),
            UIAction(title: "University", state: .on, handler: Uni)
        ])
        University.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        University.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
//        updateColor(StudAccom.menu?.selectedElements.first?.title)
//        (StudAccom.menu?.children[selectedColorIndex()] as? UIAction)?.state = .on
    }
```

**This is the function for when the register button is tapped, recording information onto firebase**

```
@objc private func registerButtonTapped() {
       emailField.resignFirstResponder()
       passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
       firstNameField.resignFirstResponder()
       lastNameField.resignFirstResponder()

       guard let firstName = firstNameField.text,
           let lastName = lastNameField.text,
           let email = emailField.text,
           let password = passwordField.text,
           !email.isEmpty,
           !password.isEmpty,
           !firstName.isEmpty,
           !lastName.isEmpty,
           password.count >= 6 else {
               alertUserLoginError()
               return
       }

       spinner.show(in: view)

       // Firebase Log In

       DatabaseManager.shared.userExists(with: email, completion: { [weak self] exists in
           guard let strongSelf = self else {
               return
           }

           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               strongSelf.spinner.dismiss()
           }

           guard !exists else {
               // user already exists
               strongSelf.alertUserLoginError(message: "Looks like a user account for that email address already exists.")
               return
           }

           FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { authResult, error in
               guard authResult != nil, error == nil else {
                   print("Error cureating user")
                   return
               }

               UserDefaults.standard.setValue(email, forKey: "email")
               UserDefaults.standard.setValue("\(firstName) \(lastName)", forKey: "name")


               let chatUser = ChatAppUser(firstName: firstName,
                                         lastName: lastName,
                                         emailAddress: email)
               DatabaseManager.shared.insertUser(with: chatUser, completion: { success in
                   if success {
                       // upload image
                       guard let image = strongSelf.imageView.image,
                           let data = image.pngData() else {
                               return
                       }
                       let filename = chatUser.profilePictureFileName
                       StorageManager.shared.uploadProfilePicture(with: data, fileName: filename, completion: { result in
                           switch result {
                           case .success(let downloadUrl):
                               UserDefaults.standard.set(downloadUrl, forKey: "profile_picture_url")
                               print(downloadUrl)
                           case .failure(let error):
                               print("Storage maanger error: \(error)")
                           }
                       })
                   }
               })

               strongSelf.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
           })
       })
   }
```

**How do I record the option selected from the pop up menu?**

I am not fully experienced with Xcode, however if there's a way of identifying and setting a string variable which represents the selected option, this way I can just say let nameOfvariable = selected option, and designate University in Firebase to that nameOfVariable. Essentially the same as the UI textfield approach:

```
let firstName = firstNameField.text,
            let lastName = lastNameField.text,
            let email = emailField.text,
            let password = passwordField.text,

let chatUser = ChatAppUser(firstName: firstName,
                                          lastName: lastName,
                                          emailAddress: email)
```